# How to require child class method to call parent class method?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

Let's say I have a parent class `A`.

```
class A
{
    public:
        A() {}

        void MyMethod()
        {
            printf( "A\n" );
        }
};
```

And I have a child class `B`.

```
class B : public A
{
    public:
        B() {}

        void MyMethod()
        {
            printf( "B\n" );
        }
};
```

Now, I would like to require class `B` to call `A::MyMethod()`, without explicitly calling it, as shown above. Resulting in:

```
A
B
```

Or

```
B
A
```

Would that be possible?

Right now `B->MyMethod()` only calls the child method.

Comment: Rather create a template function which calls a pure virtual function, that must be implemented by `B`.

Comment: If you don't call it explicitly `A::MyMethod(); MyMethod();` or `MyMethod(); A::MyMethod();` there is no way to call it *implicitly*

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How do I do that? Do you have an example for me please?

Comment: It's a common Design pattern: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method

Comment: You could use the [Non-Virtual Interface](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) idiom, and put in the "before" and/or "after" code in the base class's public member function.

Comment: Hi @Eljay, would you explain the solution for me in an answer please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Non-Virtual Interface](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) idiom has the base class define a public
non-virtual member function, and a private virtual member function that
is an override point for derived classes.

The public non-virtual member function acts as a public facing API.

The private virtual member function acts as a class hierarchy
facing API.

Separating those two concerns can be a handy technique especially
for larger projects, and for debugging purposes, and for ensuring
pre- and post- operations in the base class's public non-virtual
member function.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

namespace {

class A {
    virtual void MyMethodImpl() const {
        // Derived classes should override this virtual member function
        // and add their extra steps there.
    }
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    A() {}

    void MyMethod() const {
        cout << "A::MyMethod before steps.\n";
        MyMethodImpl();
        cout << "A::MyMethod after steps.\n";
    }
};

class B : public A {
    void MyMethodImpl() const override {
        cout << "B::MyMethodImpl extra steps.\n";
    }
public:
    B() {}
};

} // anon

int main() {
    B b;
    b.MyMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to require one class method to call another one, in C++, except for the requirement that a constructor and a destructor in a derived class must call the parent class's, in specific ways.

Except for that, there is no way to directly require this, in C++.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For reference, I actually have a different way to check this for my case. I can set a flag to see whether the required method has been called before it is required